# Jquery events not working with elements from append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently, I am creating something that will simply allow me to create tasks, click them when they are done and swipe left to get rid of them.
The problem I am having is that when the new tasks are appended, they are not affected by any of the JQuery events on in the script.

**Tl;dr:** appended divs are not affected by the below javascript, how can I fix this issue?

```
<div class="app">

  <div class="appHeader">
    <h2>Tasks</h2>

    <form class="createTask">
      <input type="text" class="createTaskInput" size="10" maxlength="25" placeholder="Type here to create your task..." //>
    </form>

  </div>

  <div class="task">
    <div class="summary">This is an example task
      <br>When you complete a task, click the red button
      <br>Should you want to remove a task, swipe left on the task.
    </div>
    <div class="completion"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  $(".completion").on({
    'touchstart': function() {
      $(this).addClass("completed")
    }
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.task").on("swipeleft", swipeleftHandler);

    function swipeleftHandler(event) {
      $(event.target).addClass("swipeleft");
    }
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".createTask").submit(function(e) {
      var value = $(".createTaskInput").val();

      $('.app').append('<div class="task"><div class="summary">' +
        value + '</div><div class="completion"></div></div>')
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you add the event listener before you add the objects.
A workaround is to add the event listener to the body like this.

```
$( "body" ).on( "swipeleft", "div.task", swipeleftHandler );
```

and

```
$(" body ").on( "touchstart", ".completion", function(){
  $(this).addClass("completed")
});
```

Comment: Hello. This fixes one of the two functions, however the function that adds the completed class to the tasks does not work still.

Comment: With part of the code is that?

Comment: see the new edit

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not binding them after you add a new task see below

```js
function swipeleftHandler(event) {
  $(event.target).addClass("swipeleft");
}

function touchHandler(event) {
  $(event.target).addClass("completed");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".completion").on('touchstart', touchHandler);
  $("div.task").on("swipeleft", swipeleftHandler);

  $(".createTask").submit(function(e) {

    var value = $(".createTaskInput").val();
    var totalExisting = $('div.task').length;

    $('.app').append('<div class="task"><div class="summary">' + value + '</div><div class="completion"></div></div>');

    var newTask = $('div.task').eq(totalExisting);
    newTask
      .on("swipeleft", swipeleftHandler)
      .on('touchstart', touchHandler);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="app">

  <div class="appHeader">
    <h2>Tasks</h2>

    <form class="createTask">
      <input type="text" class="createTaskInput" size="10" maxlength="25" placeholder="Type here to create your task..." //>
    </form>

  </div>

  <div class="task">
    <div class="summary">This is an example task
      <br>When you complete a task, click the red button
      <br>Should you want to remove a task, swipe left on the task.
    </div>
    <div class="completion"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```